# How to use TortoiseMerge from Perforce P4V?

Tags: merge, perforce, p4v, tortoisemerge

How can I configure Perforce to use the tool TortoiseMerge for diff and merging?

---

I tried arguments

```
/base:%1 /mine:%2
```

[image]

following http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html and http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Configuring_display_preferences.html#Diff . The Perforce docs say

> Specify arguments for third-party diff applications in the Arguments field:
>   Enter %1 for the name of the first file and %2 for the name of the second file. P4V replaces these placeholders with the actual filenames when calling the diff application.

Yet when I try it, TortoiseMerge errors "Can't open file %1" suggesting P4V didn't replace the arguments and left `%1` as is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly P4V's argument replacement is broken. You can use TortoiseMerge for diffing, but not merging.

To set up TortoiseMerge for diffing, use the argument string `%1 %2`

[image]

The correct arguments for merging would be

```
/base:%b /theirs:%1 /mine:%2 /merged:%r
```

However it gives this error

[image]

Presumably what's happening is that P4V fails to replace the '%b' in `/base:%b` with the appropriate file path.

Comment: Did you try configuring it as the merge tool?  What was the error?

Comment: Vote at http://www.p4ideax.com/ideas/366412/p4vs-support-for-third-party-merge-tools-eg-tortoisemerge-is

Comment: p4ideax is not really the place to report issues. Something like this is best reported to support@perforce.com or the Perforce forums

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by creating a bat file. In the bat file you can call the merge program with the correct arguments. This is the content of my bat file:

```
TortoiseMerge.exe /base:%1 /theirs:%2 /mine:%3 /merged:%4
```

The settings in p4 `%b %1 %2 %r` :
[image: Settings in P4]

As you can see I called my bat file "p4Helper.bat"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I've been beating my head against a wall for a while now trying to get this to work.

Comment: After so long, this is still broken. This is just amazing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing enhancement request because P4V does not substitute values for %b, %1, %2, and %r if these arguments are not by themselves.  For example, P4V does not substitute:

```
 /base:%b /theirs:%1 /mine:%2 /merged:%r
```

which are needed by TortoiseMerge.

However, one user reported that the command worked once he added the quotes around the pathname due to the spaces in it. For example:

start /WAIT "C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe" %1 %2 %3 /mergeoutput=%4

Thus as a workaround, you can augment the %b %1 %2 %r arguments in a script that calls TortoiseMerge. In TortoiseMerge's case, you would have a line like this:

```
 c:"\the_path_to_TortoiseMerge" /base:%1 /theirs:%2 /mine:%3 /merged:%4
```

Comment: Hi. It sounds like you work for Perforce. Could you report the bug for us?

Comment: Hello! Yes, you have already been added to the issue report for this. :-)