# Can TortoiseMerge be used as a difftool with Windows Git Bash?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-diff, tortoisegitmerge

I'm just starting to work with Git.  I would like to use TortoiseMerge as the difftool and mergetool.

In my `$HOME/.gitconfig` I have the following sections. I've removed the user and color sections for this question.

```
[merge]
    tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
    cmd = \"TortoiseMerge.exe\" -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
[diff]
    tool = tortoisemerge
[difftool "tortoisemerge"]
    cmd = \"TortoiseMerge.exe\" -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
```

If I type tortoisemerge at the Git Bash prompt it loads. It is known to be on the path. But if I type the command I get the following error.

```
Rich:mygittest (master *)
$ git difftool
error: 'tortoisemerge' can only be used to resolve merges
merge tool candidates: kompare emerge vimdiff
No known merge resolution program available.
external diff died, stopping at readme.txt.
Rich:mygittest (master *)
$
```

What am I not understanding to make this work?
Tortoisemerge is installed with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The following settings work fine for me. However, I am using TortoiseGit not TortoiseSVN. Notice the difference in the parameters for diff.

```
[diff]
  tool = tortoisediff
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[merge]
  tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool]
  prompt = false
  keepBackup = false
[difftool "tortoisediff"]
  cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -mine "$REMOTE" -base "$LOCAL"
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
  cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -base "$BASE" -theirs "$REMOTE" -mine "$LOCAL" -merged "$MERGED"
```

Comment: TortoiseMerge has an issue with the way Git mangles the parameters. Because TortoiseMerge uses a colon to separate parameter name from value, Git puts quotes around both when dealing with filenames with spaces. TortoiseGitMerge allows a space and relieves the problem.

Comment: It is msys bash that mangles the quotes. Apparently it should work with tortoise git 1.8

Comment: [Perforce can't cope with colons either](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12638596/284795). We should ask TortoiseMerge to add an alternative syntax.

Comment: It works for me when having `TortoiseSVN` which has `TortoiseMerge.exe`. Yes, `diff` with `TortoiseMerge.exe`, not `TortoiseIDiff.exe`. `git difftool` calls out TortoiseMerge GUI, very convenient! `TortoiseMerge` is the best!

Answer (score 7):

So that filenames with spaces are handled correctly, you should change the last line of @melbourn's answer to

```
cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -base "$BASE" -theirs "$REMOTE" -mine "$LOCAL" -merged "$MERGED"
```

Comment: What's the difference?  Is it (just) that the colons in the parameters have been replaced by spaces?  Should a similar change be made for the difftool?  I don't know if it's worth editing the original answer, or whether there is some reason for the colons..

Comment: The colons are replaced with spaces. The argument handling code can accept either colons or spaces. But quotes around a filename which has spaces in it will not be handled correctly if the quotes are not at either the start or the end of 'words'.

Comment: @jwg I have now modified my answer to take your advice into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler way, just run these commands in git bash:

```bash
git config --global merge.tool tortoisemerge

git config --global diff.tool tortoisediff
git config --global difftool.tortoisediff.cmd "TortoiseGitMerge \$LOCAL \$REMOTE"
```

It's done.

**----for futher reading----**

There are other settings you may need:

```bash
# you may want to disable prompt or merge backup
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
git config --global difftool.prompt false
git config --global mergetool.prompt false

# set the path only when it's not found in system path
git config --global mergetool.tortoisemerge.path "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe" 
git config --global difftool.tortoisdiff.path "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe"
```

To set the mergetool, you just need to set the right mergetool name. It's official supported.

Git for windows installer includes a shell file for running tortoisegitmerge as a merge tool. It locates at `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools`. (Git provides 4 variables for merging: `$BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED`, you can check them in the shell file.)

You can check all supported merge/diff tools supported on your machine with the command:

```bash
git difftool --tool-help
git mergetool --tool-help
```

Run tortoisegitmerge as git diff tool is not official supported by git, maybe it's because this tool doesn't support directory compare (`git difftool -d`).  So you need to config the difftool cmd to use it as a git difftool.

The tortoisegitmerge tool has a manual at:
https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegitmerge/tme-automation.html
You can find the simplest way to do diff file is:
`TortoiseGitMerge BaseFilePath MyFilePath [ TheirFilePath ]`.
So I use this way for git difftool's command.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Klas Mellbourn! Saved me a lotta time.
One shortcoming is, newly `Added` or `Removed` files in the repository will not show up during the difftool command execution. There's nothing to compare them to! Here's what I did on top of this:
(Inspired by my co-worker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063859/4568373)).

1. Create a file named `empty.empty` in `$Home` directory (execute `start ~` in your bash). And as the name suggests, keep it empty.
2. Create another file named `tortoisediff.sh` in `$Home/bin` directory with following content

:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $LOCAL $REMOTE seem to be swapped
# $1 is $LOCAL
# $2 is $REMOTE

difftool='/c/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe'
NULL="/dev/null"
empty="C:/home/empty.empty"

if [ "$1" == "$NULL" ]; then
    echo "Added: " "$2"
    "$difftool" /base:"$empty" /mine:"$2" /readonly:"$empty"
elif [ "$2" == "$NULL" ]; then
    echo 'Removed: ' "$1"
    "$difftool" /base:"$1" /readonly:"$1" /mine:"$empty"
else
    echo 'Modified' "$2"
    "$difftool" /base:"$1" /basename:"$1" /readonly:"$1" /mine:"$2" /minename:"$2"
fi

# Checkout https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegitmerge/tme-automation.html for more
```

3. Modify your .gitconfig file (Line 11 of the answer)

   `cmd = tortoisediff.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"`

This would now make difftool refer to tortoisediff.sh instead of opening the application directly.

4. **Keep in mind:** you'd have to run `git add .` followed by `git difftool --staged` instead of simply `git difftool`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[diff]
  tool = tortoisediff
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[merge]
  tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool]
  prompt = false
  keepBackup = false
[difftool "tortoisediff"]
  cmd = \""C:/Users/$USER/Desktop/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
  cmd = \""C:/Users/$USER/Desktop/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
```

This worked for me, using TortoiseMerge 1.6.7 (Portable)

Answer (score 0):

When rebasing, I strongly recommend switch `$theirs` and `$mine`, because it is different when you merge and rebase-merge. Check here:

[What is the precise meaning of "ours" and "theirs" in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576415/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-in-git)

So, if you only use mergetool to rebase like me, do:

```
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -base "$BASE" -theirs "$LOCAL" -mine "$REMOTE" -merged "$MERGED"
```

Answer (score 0):

For using the TortoiseMerge with an existing TortoiseSVN installation in Windows:

```
[guitool "VisualDiff"]
    cmd = git difftool -y \"$FILENAME\"
    needsfile = yes
    noconsole = yes
[diff]
    tool = tortoisediff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[merge]
    tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
[difftool "tortoisediff"]
    cmd = \""W:/Programs/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" "/mine:$REMOTE" "/base:$LOCAL"
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
    cmd = \""W:/Programs/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" "/base:$BASE" "/theirs:$REMOTE" "/mine:$LOCAL" "/merged:$MERGED"
```